# reload parent page after close DHTML popup

Tags: javascript

i have dhtml popup image with image map closing window

```
    <MAP NAME=myimagemap>
<AREA HREF=javascript:openLiveHelp() SHAPE=RECT COORDS=0,0,400,197>
<AREA HREF=javascript:openLiveHelp() SHAPE=RECT COORDS=0,157,213,257>
<AREA HREF=javascript:closeDHTML() SHAPE=RECT COORDS=237,157,400,257>
</MAP>
```

i want to add refresh to the parent when close the popup.

someone have an idea
Thank you

Comment: That is some pretty serious 2004 coding right there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

You can access parent window using 'window.opener', so, write something like the following in the child window

Comment: Thank you Sir, i tried -<MAP NAME=myimagemap>
<AREA HREF=javascript:openLiveHelp() SHAPE=RECT COORDS=0,0,400,197>
<AREA HREF=javascript:openLiveHelp() SHAPE=RECT COORDS=0,157,213,257>
<AREA HREF=javascript:closeDHTML() SHAPE=RECT COORDS=237,157,400,257>
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
</MAP>
but nothing realy happen just closing the popup without reload the parent.